# Не передаётся управление обратно в исходный код. Программа выключается после выхода из подпрограммы assembler

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

После выполнения ассемблера, работа программы почему-то заканчивается.

Если идти отладчиком, пишет

1. при переходе в эту функцию из основной программы:

> Файл исходного кода отличается от того, который был использован при построении модуля. Воспользоваться отладчиком несмотря на это?

Но в файл ассемблера все равно переходит.

2. В конце программы ассемблера  пишет что не найден
   exe_common.inl.

Также, когда создавал второй проект с теми же файлами, выдало ошибку

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PER в функции
>   _main
>
> Неразрешённых вешних элементов: 1

### Код основной программы на с++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;


extern "C" int PER(int*ARR1, int*ARR2, int *Result, int len1, int len2, int&level);
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    ifstream f1;
    ofstream f2;
    f1.open("input.txt");
    if (!f1.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Open file failed." << endl;
        //system("pause");
        //return 0;
    }
    f2.open("output.txt");
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned int start_time = clock();
    int l, n1, n2, k = 0;
    f1 >> n1>> n2;
    int *mas1 = new int[n1];
    int *mas2 = new int[n2];
    int *result = new int[10];
    f2 << "Массив 1: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        f1 >> mas1[i];
        f2 <<mas1[i]<<" ";
    }
    f2 << endl;
    f2 << "Массив 2: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        f1 >> mas2[i];
        f2 << mas2[i]<<" ";
    }
    f2 << endl;
    int n=0;
    int level = 0;
    n = PER(mas1, mas2, result, n1, n2,level);

    f2 << "Общие элементы: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        f2 << result[i] << " ";
    }
    f2 << "\nКоличество циклов: " << level << endl;
    unsigned int end_time = clock();
    unsigned int search_time = end_time - start_time;
    f2 << "Время затраченное программой на расчёт: " << search_time / 1000. << " секунд" << endl;
    f2.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

### Код подпрограммы на ассемблере

```
.586P
.MODEL FLAT, C
PUBLIC PER
_TEXT SEGMENT
PER PROC C, 
ARR1:DWORD,ARR2:DWORD,Result:DWORD,len1:DWORD,len2:DWORD,level:DWORD
.data
count dword 0
.code
    mov eax,len1
    add eax,len2
    mov len1,eax


    xor eax,eax
    xor esi, esi
    xor edi, edi
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ebx, ARR1
    mov edx, ARR2
    mov esi, Result
    add ecx, len1

again:  
    mov eax,[ebx]
    inc level
    cmp eax,[edx]

    je point1
    jl point2
    jg point3

point1: 
    add ebx,4
    add edx,4
    mov [esi],eax
    add esi,4
    sub ecx,2
    inc count
    cmp ecx,0

    je finish
    jmp again

point2: 
    add ebx,4
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx,0

    je finish
    jmp again

point3: 
    add edx,4
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx,0

    je finish
    jmp again
finish:     
    mov eax,count
LEAVE
RET
PER ENDP
_TEXT ENDS
END
```

Инпутный файл:

```
7
10
1 2 5 13 22 33 35
2 4 13 22 25 26 30 31 33 35
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ` — попробуйте изменить строки `PUBLIC PER` и `PER PROC C, ` на `PUBLIC _PER` и `_PER PROC C, ` соотвественно.

Comment: @Arhad пробовал раньше и сейчас попробовал, для верности, не помогает((

Comment: Похоже, что и в первом случае сборка проходит неудачно, и запускается последний рабочий вариант. Оттого и несоответствие кода.

Comment: @VTT первый случай повторяется даже если удаляю все дебаги